# How to remotely collect windows performance counters through sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, performancecounter, sqlclr

I'd like my application (which is deployed to thousands of locations) to be able to monitor its own environment, in particular the sql server box. When the SQL Server is local, this is easy to do as I can use the System.Diagnostics library and collect the windows performance counters through that. When the SQL server is remote however I have a problem because I cannot guarantee that my c# application (a windows service in this case) has access to the remote sql server machine OTHER THAN the fact that I know it can access the SQL Server.

Any ideas on how I can collect the windows performance counters off that machine through SQL?

One way I've thought of is to use SQL CLR, but it seems to require UNSAFE access, which I'm pretty sure I don't want.

Thanks

Comment: Just for clarification, you want your database to be able to collect performance counter statistics of the machine running your application, correct?

Comment: MS-SQL CLR has a SAFE mode that I believe you can use given your requirements - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345101.aspx

Comment: @M.Babcock I want my application or SQL Server to collect performance counter statistics of the machine running SQL Server.

Comment: @ron tornambe I know it has a SAFE mode but the System.performance counters seem to require hire privelages than that based on my tests. I believe that is because getting performance counters through System.Diagnostics requires registry access. I don't know if WMI is better or if that will require the same level of access

Comment: @Mark - From your C# application you can call [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ffskxdc.aspx) overload of the PerformanceCounter constructor to connect to a remote counter. The trick will be determining which PC it needs to gather statistics from and guaranteeing it has the right permissions.

Comment: @M.Babcock but that's the point, i can't guarantee that I will have the proper privaleges. All i can guarantee is that i have access to SQL Server

Comment: @Mark - Your options here are really simple. 1. Guarantee that your application runs on the same machine as SQL Server (if not the one you have now then another that can do the simple task). *OR* 2. Deal with an UNSAFE SQL CLR assembly. There really isn't any magic here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mark as you stated in the comments

> "i can't guarantee that I will have the proper privileges"

Either you have to write some kind of functionality into your installer that is going to make sure you have the proper privileges (maybe won't install without admin setting privileges) for remote perf. counters access.

You didn't state exactly what you were trying to monitor, however, might I suggest using the built int SQL Server Dynamic Management Views (DMV's)

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188754.aspx)
[Good Articles Videos](http://www.brentozar.com/?s=DMV%20periodic)
[Very Useful Examples](http://sqlserverperformance.wordpress.com/2011/12/28/sql-server-2008-diagnostic-information-queries-december-2011/)

these have become very robust in recent releases of SQL server and allow you to monitor the majority of the stats you would work with in perfmon (CPU, IO, MEMORY, many more).  Perhaps not as much granularity as perfmon but usually I find them to be more useful then perfmon nowadays for quick pertinent data.  And as long as your connection string user has admin rights you don't have to worry about server privileges.  And this functionality is allready built into sql-server  Give it a look see.

---

Edit ...
@Mark Here are some DMV scripts I use to get IO time on a database, not as exact as PerfMon however it allows you to focus in on a specific database file.

Check out the "dm_io_virtual_file_stats" DMV

```
select
read_stall_ms = case when num_of_reads = 0 then 0 else (io_stall_read_ms/num_of_reads) end,
write_stall_ms = case when io_stall_write_ms = 0 then 0 else (io_stall_write_ms/num_of_writes) end,
total_stall_ms = case when (num_of_reads = 0 and num_of_writes = 0) then 0 else (io_stall/(num_of_reads + num_of_writes)) end,
db = db_name(vfs.database_id),
mf.physical_name,
vfs.*
from sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats(null, null) as vfs
join sys.master_files as mf on vfs.database_id = mf.database_id and vfs.file_id = mf.file_id
order by total_stall_ms desc

select m.database_id,
db_name(m.database_id) as database_name,
m.file_id,
m.name as file_name, 
m.physical_name, 
m.type_desc,
fs.num_of_reads, 
fs.num_of_bytes_read, 
fs.io_stall_read_ms, 
fs.num_of_writes, 
fs.num_of_bytes_written, 
fs.io_stall_write_ms
from sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats(NULL, NULL) fs
join sys.master_files m on fs.database_id = m.database_id and fs.file_id = m.file_id
```

Something a little fancier ...

```
select db_name(d.database_id) as database_name, 
quotename(object_schema_name(d.object_id, d.database_id)) + N'.' + quotename(object_name(d.object_id, d.database_id)) as object_name,
d.database_id,
d.object_id,
d.page_io_latch_wait_count,
d.page_io_latch_wait_in_ms,
d.range_scans,
d.index_lookups,
case when mid.database_id is null then 'N' else 'Y' end as missing_index_identified
from (select 
        database_id,
        object_id,
        row_number() over (partition by database_id order by sum(page_io_latch_wait_in_ms) desc) as row_number,
        sum(page_io_latch_wait_count) as page_io_latch_wait_count,
        sum(page_io_latch_wait_in_ms) as page_io_latch_wait_in_ms,
        sum(range_scan_count) as range_scans,
        sum(singleton_lookup_count) as index_lookups
    from sys.dm_db_index_operational_stats(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
    where page_io_latch_wait_count > 0
    group by database_id, object_id ) as d
left join (select distinct database_id, object_id from sys.dm_db_missing_index_details) as mid on mid.database_id = d.database_id and mid.object_id = d.object_id
```

Comment: I think this is the best approach. Unfortunately, i'm trying to collect Physical disk - Ave Disk sec / read which I can't find in the DMVs.

Comment: @Mark Check out "dm_io_virtual_file_stats" for I/O there are a couple of other DMV's for IO as well, see Edit for exacmples

Answer (score 1):

If you sign your assembly, you can create a login from the assembly, grant it the server-level permission to run unsafe assemblies, and create the assembly from the dll.  This allows you to run unsafe assemblies w/o having to turn the trustworthy flag on the database on.

Comment: Sounds promissing but what do you mean by "create a login from the assembly"?

Comment: create asymmetric key [ArbitraryKeyName] from executable file = 'path to dll'; create login [ArbitraryLoginName] from asymmetric key [ArbitraryKeyName]

Answer (score -2):

I would think you need something more robust than  self-rolled SQL CLR for this. MS has a tool for precisly this called SCOM.

I have had very good results in envs with 50 servers.

You collect loads of configurable data with built in point in time reports, data warehousing and alerts.

[good wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Center_Operations_Manager)

[technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/microsoft-system-center-operations-manager.aspx)

Comment: As stated in the question this application is deployed to thousands of locations. It's not really possible for me to deploy SCOM to thousands of locations just in order to collect a few performance counters from one machine.